# Did I damage my kitten by accidentally forcefully opening her eyes?

Tags: cats, health, eye-disease

I might have accidentally opened the right eye of a week old kitten. I was holding her head in order to place the feeding bottle in her mouth. She then squirmed (like she always does when trying to find the feeding bottle) and this stretched her face enough for her right eyelid to open. Her exact age should be 8-9 days, and the force applied to her face wasn't really different to how I've been holding her all the time when I feed her (since 1-2 days old); this makes me think that the eyelid was actually ready to open (because they should be sealed really tight when they're not ready yet, right?) and then it just happened when she rubbed against my hand.

What signs should I look for in order to know if the eye was ready for it or if I have caused damage? Also, will she be able to close the eyelid by herself (to sleep) or is there something I must do about it?

Edit: I just saw them while they're sleeping and she has both eyes closed just fine. I guess I don't have to worry about the part about being able to close it now.

Comment: Our kittens ar only exactly 7 days old and both eyes are partially open, should i be concerned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The eyelids open at about 9 to 14 days. So your kitty is at the right age for it.

In the [When Do Newborn Kittens Eyes Open?](https://www.vetinfo.com/when-do-newborn-kittens-eyes-open.html)  at Vetinfo, it is given that:

> Kittens' eyes are undeveloped and overly sensitive to light when they are first born, so their bodies keep their eyelids tightly shut. So you should not rush the eye-opening process or prod at a kitten's eyes.

> If necessary the you may gently, with cotton ball lightly covered in warm water, wipe any discharge away from a kitten's eyes or in order to help keep swelling down.